# Integrate extracted PDF content with django-haystack

Tags: python, solr, django-haystack

I have extracted PDF/DOCX content with Solr and I've suceeded to establish some search queries using the following Solr URL dedicated to this :

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/select?q=Lycee
```

I would like to establish a such query with django-haystack. I have found this link which is talking about the issue :

https://github.com/toastdriven/django-haystack/blob/master/docs/rich_content_extraction.rst

But there is no "FileIndex" class with django-haystack (2.0.0-beta). How can I integrate a such search within django-haystack ?

Answer (score 1):

The "FileIndex" referenced in the documentation is a hypothetical subclass of haystack.indexes.SearchIndex. Here is an example:

```
from haystack import indexes
from myapp.models import MyFile

class FileIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    title = indexes.CharField(model_attr='title')
    owner = indexes.CharField(model_attr='owner__name')


    def get_model(self):
        return MyFile

    def index_queryset(self, using=None):
        return self.get_model().objects.all()

    def prepare(self, obj):
        data = super(FileIndex, self).prepare(obj)

        # This could also be a regular Python open() call, a StringIO instance
        # or the result of opening a URL. Note that due to a library limitation
        # file_obj must have a .name attribute even if you need to set one
        # manually before calling extract_file_contents:
        file_obj = obj.the_file.open()

        extracted_data = self.backend.extract_file_contents(file_obj)

        # Now we'll finally perform the template processing to render the
        # text field with *all* of our metadata visible for templating:
        t = loader.select_template(('search/indexes/myapp/myfile_text.txt', ))
        data['text'] = t.render(Context({'object': obj,
                                        'extracted': extracted_data}))

        return data
```

So `extracted_data` would be replaced with whatever process you came up with to extract the PDF/DOCX content. You would then update your template to include that data.